# How to solve "'cudafe' died due to signal 11"?

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I am compiling libbsc (compression library for GPU). During make, I am receiving,

```
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/adler32/adler32.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/bwt/divsufsort/divsufsort.c
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/bwt/bwt.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/coder/coder.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/coder/qlfc/qlfc.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/coder/qlfc/qlfc_model.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/filters/detectors.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/filters/preprocessing.cpp
nvcc -DLIBBSC_SORT_TRANSFORM_SUPPORT -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3  -lcuda -lcudart -DLIBBSC_CUDA_SUPPORT -Xcompiler -openmp -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -c libbsc/libbsc/libbsc.cu
nvcc error   : 'cudafe' died due to signal 11 (Invalid memory reference)
nvcc error   : 'cudafe' core dumped
make: *** [libbsc.o] Error 139
```

What does this 'cudafe' died due to signal 11 (Invalid memory reference) mean?

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the program, due to a bug, tried to access memory it had not allocated. The hardware, then the system noticed.